# My new website pages are not displaying their pictures properly

Tags: html, css

[The html code on the actual webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLUc4.jpg)

Hello. I am having some problems with pictures not properly displaying on a website. I have added the picture and created a div.tag for it and also added it to the CSS but it simply will not show properly. http://mala.co.uk/projects-sw-adelphi.html is one of the new webpages that I have added. http://mala.co.uk/projects-cat-a-eastcheap.html is a webpage with a picture being displayed properly.  It is really baffling me why the new pages I have added have the pictures being cut off while the older pages render the pictures perfectly. The Eastcheap picture is how the size should be (more square) but new pages are showing the images more rectangular. Any help would be massively appreciated. Kind Regards

Comment: The problem is that they are cut off and not original size?

Comment: Stack Overflow allows you to paste your code on the site with your question. please utilize these tools and attach your code here. user's do not always know where your links lead to.

Comment: Please define ***"properly"***.

Comment: None of the pictures on the website is displayed properly, all of the pictures have been cut off to match the description height on the right side.

Answer (score -1):

You have set a specific `height` for the `large-6 columns` divs. Changing that height has an influence on the image, as it is relative to the parent div container.

I am not sure how that height is generated or if you have hard coded that. It might also depend on the text on the right col, which will change the height of the left col.

Edit: I have edit your code in the inspector. It looks like that.

`<div class="large-6 columns panel-container" data-equalizer-watch="" style="height: 450px;">`

[image]

Comment: You're right. I also checked the site with the inspector and found that the images are actually background images for the div container ( `projects-adelphi-panel` ). The actual images are set to `display: none !important;`.